# Hello, I'm trying to make a object play an audio source on colliosion with another object, buts its not working?

Tags: audio, collision-detection, collision

[Here is my script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nucuz.png)
[This is the only error message in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qVnZ.png)

I am using the 2D Unity engine by the way and I have the audio source selected in Unity on the right object. This is probably a very easy fix, that I just not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

maybe try GetComponent <AudioSource> instead of AudioSoruce?